# jquery ajax post request callback doesnt work

Tags: jquery, .net, json, ajax

I'm trying to post data to my controller, this is my post request ;

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Shipment/SaveTrackingNumber/",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType : "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result.success == true) {
                        newNotify.SuccessNotify("Kaydetme İşlemi", "Kargo Kodu Kaydedildi!", Page.Time);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location = "/Order";
                        }, (Page.Time + 1000));
                    }
                    else {
                        newNotify.WarningNotify("Kaydetme İşlemi", "Hata Oluştu!", Page.Time + 1000);
                    }
                }

            })
```

When the request comes in my method, it gives 405 error after few lines, my controller method returns json data but success callback doesnt work. When i try to debug javascript and move step by step it works. Its weird , how can i solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

405 isn't a success so it will never reach

success: function (result) {}

It will reach error.

error: function (result) {}

If you need to reach success you need to return a 2** http code

Alternatively you could use always which files regardless of the http status code

```
.always(function(result) {
    alert( result );
  });
```